# Postman - flags for different requests on different environments?

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, postman

I have serviceA, serviceB, serviceC..., up to service L.

I have a collection with requests for all those services.

Is it possible to set somehow flags for postman runner for requests to be run on different environments?

What I would like to do is to run requestes for all services on DEV environment, but on TEST don't run requests for serviceL and for QA/UAT don't run requests for serviceK and serviceL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newman has an option to select the environment you want to use, the flag `-e`

Then, you can run `newman run mycollection.json -e serviceAEnv` to run the suite with the environment for service A.

Then you can create a script to run many of these commands:

```
declare -a arr=("serviceAEnv" "serviceBEnv" "serviceCEnv")

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   eval "newman run mycollection.json -e $i"
done
```

OBS: It's also very easy to run commands in [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/450329/2252076), [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52575123/2252076), or [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8496537/2252076).

OBS 2: See all Newman's options [here](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/command_line_integration_with_newman/#options) or by running `newman run -h`

OBS 3: To to this using Postman Runner, you would need to write a lot of control flow code, using the [nextRequest](http://thatsabug.com/2019/02/01/postman_runner.html#postman-flows-with-setnextrequest) function. It will surely be messy, because it's complicated and you would be mixing the request code with how to execute the request, breaking the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). I would not suggest it.